Unable to make kubernetes deployment using sbt-kubeyml
I'm trying to create deployment.yaml file using sbt-kubeyml.
I'm using scala 2.13.4 and sbt 1.9.6.
First I have created simple project in scala, with simple akka http get route. Then I have created its docker image using sbt-native-packager which is working fine.
Then I tried to make its kubernetes deployment and service which are:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world-deployment

spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world-label
  template:
    metadata:
      name: hello-world-pod
      labels:
        app: hello-world-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world-container
          image: simple-hello-world-with-sbt-kubeyml:0.0.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8099
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-world-service

spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: hello-world-label
  ports:
    - port: 8099
      targetPort: 8099

Above deployment and service is working perfectly fine. I have tested on postman.
Now I want to create above deployment using sbt-kubeyml for this I took help from text. Now my,
plugins.sbt:
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeReleases

addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.9.16")

addSbtPlugin("org.vaslabs.kube" % "sbt-kubeyml" % "0.4.1")

build.sbt:
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.*
import sbt.*
import kubeyml.deployment.plugin.Keys.*

ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "SimpleHelloWorldWithSbtKubeyml"
  )

enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin, KubeDeploymentPlugin, KubeServicePlugin)

fork := true

// other commands for docker

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.6.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.7.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.5.2",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.4.11",
  "io.netty" % "netty-transport-native-epoll" % "4.1.99.Final" classifier "linux-x86_64",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.7.0"
)

lazy val deploymentSettings = Seq(
  kube / namespace := "hello-world-ns",
  kube / application := "hello-world-dp"
)

Above project builds fine without any error.
I wrote kubeyml:gen in sbt-shell, it created two files deployment.yaml and service.yaml in target/kubeyml. Now the problem is, these files do not have the namespace and application name which I specified through build.sbt.
I'm just trying to change default namespace and application name so that I can check whether build.sbt is making changes in deployment.yaml or not. Currently it is not doing so. Guide me how can I do this?
